# problem with Zend URL helper $this->url

Tags: zend-framework, url

I have situation with Zend route & $this->url method

IN my bootstrap.php I have few routes as

```
 $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        'dashboard',
        array(
            'action'     => 'index',
            'controller' => 'index',
            'module'     => 'dashboard',
            'isAdmin'    => true
        )
    );
    $router->addRoute('dashboard', $route);

$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        'logout',
        array(
            'action'     => 'logout',
            'controller' => 'index',
            'module'     => 'main',
            'isAdmin'    => true
        )
    );
    $router->addRoute('logout', $route);

$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        'manage-users',
        array(
            'action'     => 'list',
            'controller' => 'index',
            'module'     => 'main',
            'isAdmin'    => true
        )
    );
    $router->addRoute('manage-users', $route);

$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        'edit-user/:id',
        array(
            'action'     => 'edit',
            'controller' => 'index',
            'module'     => 'main',
        ),
         array('id' => '[0-9]+')
    );
    $router->addRoute('edit-user', $route);


 $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        '/manage-subcat/:ident',
        array(
            'action'     => 'index',
            'controller' => 'subcategory',
            'module'     => 'category',
            'ident'      => '',
            array(
                'ident' => '[a-zA-Z-_0-9]+',
            )
        )
    );
    $router->addRoute('manage-subcat', $route);
```

take a case of last route

in my view when I write

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array ('controller'=> 'subcategory', 'action'=> 'index', 'module'=> 'category', 'ident' => $cats->catident ), 'manage-subcat', true ) ?>"><?php echo $cat->CategoryName ?></a>
```

I get url as **http://127.0.0.10/manage-subcat**

& when I disable the last route in bootstrap & then I write in my view file

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array ('controller'=> 'subcategory', 'action'=> 'index', 'module'=> 'category', 'ident' => $cats->catident ) ) ?>"><?php echo $cat->CategoryName ?></a>
```

I get Url as same  **http://127.0.0.10/category/subcategory**

Ideally I should get **http://127.0.0.10/category/subcategory/ident/some-category** for this one

& for previous one it should be **http://127.0.0.10/manage-subcat/ident/some-category**

This code sample is not working with custom routes as well as traditional routes, and I am trying to determine why this sample is not working correctly.

Comment: The "validation" array for that last route is inside the "defaults" array.

Comment: @zerocrates u mean to say I should change it to this >> 

`$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
            '/manage-subcat/:ident',
            array(
                'action'     => 'index',
                'controller' => 'subcategory',
                'module'     => 'category',
                'ident'      => '',
            ),
            array(
                    'ident' => '[a-zA-Z-_0-9]+',
                )
        );
        $router->addRoute('manage-subcat', $route);` 

OK that was a silly mistake & I did that too yet URL is not having :ident property in it

Comment: You should use the [static router](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.static) for the parameterless routes

Answer (score 1):

Besides the route declaration formatting error noted by [zerocrates](https://stackoverflow.com/users/331137/zerocrates), could it be simply a typo in your code?

I notice you use `$cat->CategoryName` (singular `$cat`) in one place and `$cats->catident` (plural `$cats`) in another.

If passed a `null` parameter value, the router will omit that parameter from the generated URL.

Comment: hey man ur right u know copy paste mistake ...... I also started using Static routes. things are good again thanks

Comment: @ankur You may want to check this as the right answer (check mark button)

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the show of support but I don't think ankur is coming back any time soon ;)